# На хостинге не работает авторизация на сайте с помощью CURL

Tags: php, curl

Делаю `POST` запрос на авторизацию с помощью `CURL`. На `OpenServer`'e (локалке) работает авторизация нормально, а когда заливаю файлы на хостинг то с хостинга не авторизовывается. Сервер отвечает редиректом на главную. Файл `cookie.txt` имеет права 777 и запись куки в него происходит при попытке авторизоваться. Что такое происходит понять не могу, может Вы мне поможете разобраться. Может быть какие то настройки на хостинге нужно делать? У меня VPS - `Operating System: linux / rhel ( CentOS 7.2 x64 cPanel11 5 )`

```
function authSite($data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt","w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 36);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://SITE.RU/index.php");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, "http://SITE.RU/index.php");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $result = curl_exec ($login);
    if (curl_errno($login)) {
        return curl_error($login);
    } else {
        return $result;
    }

    curl_close ($login);
        unset($login);
    }


    $dataPost = "login=LOGIN&password=PASSWORD&submit=sing in";
    $res = authSite($dataPost);

print_r($res);
```

Выдает следующий код:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="2;URL=index.php">redirectArray
(
    [0] => 
)
```

Comment: Добавьте `var_dump($result);` сразу после вызова `cur` и посмотрите, что выводит

Comment: phpinfo(); и посмотрите стоит ли на сервере curl модуль

Comment: @rjhdby после использования `var_dump($result);` я понял, что авторизация все таки происходит, там на сайте такая авторизация - после авторизации выводится пустая страница с редиректом на главную, видимо проблема в том что CURL запрос не следует за всеми переадресациями или что то не так с куки. Можете посоветовать какие еще опции нужно добавить?